# What's happened to 'The Doors of Stone'?

Tags: the-kingkiller-chronicle

I read *The Name of the Wind* a few years ago and was grumpy to find out that the following two books had not been published. The second book has finally come out, and I want to know if anyone knows when the third book will be released.

**The author's site claims that book 2 and 3 were written a while ago and just needed to go through some editing.**

Comment: He's playing with his charity and not writing.

Comment: @KDog "He's playing with his charity and not writing". Kinda shot your own complaint in the foot there, buddy.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/isbook3outyet/

Answer (score 12):

As of September 2023, there have been no additional updates on a release date. In May he stated [on his blog](https://www.tor.com/2023/09/06/patrick-rothfuss-twitch-series-narrow-road/) that the book was still in the works and that we would be advised of it on that channel (or his Twitch) first, rather than hearing from another source like Amazon.

> *It’s something that I still don’t know how to come to grips with. And
> the only solution I do have is the promise I made years back: That
> when there *is* a publication date for DOS, or I put out a different
> book, you’ll hear about it directly from me first. And no matter where
> else I make the announcement. (Like today on Twitch, for example.)
> I’ll also post about it here on the blog.*

Rothfuss is, however releasing a fix-up of one of his earlier short stories, a novella called *The Narrow Road Between Desires*, largely based on a short story called [The Lightning Tree](https://kingkiller.fandom.com/wiki/The_Lightning_Tree).

Given that he's evidently continuing to work on other books (this being his ninth since this question was first posed) we may have a while longer to wait before *Doors of Stone* comes out.

---

<s>As of December 2022, there have been no additional updates.</s>

Per [*WinterisComing.net - "Rumor: The Doors of Stone is in editing and has a release date?"*](https://winteriscoming.net/2022/08/24/new-doors-of-stone-rumor-the-book-is-in-editing-and-has-a-release-date/)*, Rothfuss held a kickstarter at the end of 2021 that stated that he would read the entire first chapter of the book if the financial goal was met. Despite that happening in February 2022, no additional readings have been made and refunds have since been made to pledges. It remains to be seen whether that's because he's not written even the first chapter or whether this is because re-writes have been required in the interim.

You may also wish to note that at this point he's written **eight** entire books (that aren't *The Doors of Stone*) since this question was first asked.

<sup>*</sup><sup>**Spoiler: no it doesn't**</sup>

---

<s>As of September 2021, Rothfuss reports on his regular video-blog that he still needs to send a completed copy to his publisher and that it's costing him a great deal of time to get the book sorted. It's not clear whether he means that he's still writing it or just in consultation with his editors, but the former seems likely.</s>

He has, however, released a short 'prologue', which confirms that he's written at least a page of the book.

<s>As of July 2021, no further updates on the release date (or progress in writing).</s>

> “**No news on book 3**,” he said. “Rest assured that if there was news
> there would be a press release and it’d be on my blog and it’d be the
> first thing that I say.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Patrick Rothfuss talks The Doors of Stone, The Wise Man’s Fear anniversary edition](https://winteriscoming.net/2021/07/07/patrick-rothfuss-talks-the-doors-of-stone-10th-anniversary-edition-wise-mans-fear/)</sup></sub>

---

<s>As of March 2021, the book is still being written. It sounds like Rothfuss is suffering from a mixture of writer's block, paranoia about [third-album syndrome](https://reelrabble.wordpress.com/2018/07/20/third-album-syndrome/) and depression.</s>

---

<s>As of **February 2017**, the book remains stuck in [development hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_hell). The author, unhappy with the final edited product has apparently taken the book back to the drawing board for extensive rewriting.</s>

<s>> **Q. Is there a publication date for book 3? No:**</s>

> **PR:** *I would share it if I had it.*
>
> **Q. How does he feel the writing is going on book 3 today (as opposed to
> two years ago, when he jokingly rated it 3.5 stars out of 5 on
> Goodreads)?**
>
> **PR:** *It’s at best a star and a half because I dismantled a big piece of it
> and haven’t quite put it back together.*
>
> <sub>[Patrick Rothfuss Announces The Name of the Wind Tenth Anniversary Edition and Shares Updates on The Kingkiller Chronicle Book 3](https://www.tor.com/2017/02/03/patrick-rothfuss-kingkiller-chronicle-book-3-update/)</sub>

---

<s>The author has confirmed that the book will end the series, but that future works will be set in the same continuity</s>

> **Q. Will book 3 will be the last in the series?**

> ***PR:** Yes and no. Book 3 closes this arc of story. Book 3 will not be the final book set in this world. Big distinction there!*
>
> **Q. But will he wrap everything up?**
>
> **PR:** *Think of any series that was wrapped up. Think of The Lord of the Rings, which has a pretty solid ending: Was everything wrapped up
> at the end of the third book of Lord of the Rings? No. That’s what
> happens in any sort of realistic world, in any sort of realistic story
> with realistic characters. There was some good closure in that book,
> but what happened with Aragorn, and Minas Tirith, and now that he was
> back? […] And what about Sam and his kids? What really happened to the
> Grey Havens? Did Frodo every bounce back from that? What did Gandalf
> talk to Tom Bombadil about? There’s a ton of unanswered questions—so
> yeah, that’s actually the mark of a good story, and so I won’t be
> answering everything, but the truth is, you don’t want me to. You
> might think you want me to, but you don’t. And even if you really do,
> I still won’t. Just because it’s impossible.*
>
> <sub>[Patrick Rothfuss Announces The Name of the Wind Tenth Anniversary Edition and Shares Updates on The Kingkiller Chronicle Book 3](https://www.tor.com/2017/02/03/patrick-rothfuss-kingkiller-chronicle-book-3-update/)</sub>

Comment: Oof... Not a good update to see...

Comment: @fez - Him and GRRM need to form a support group

Comment: @Valorum ... Any bets on which will be first:  *The Doors of Stone* or *The Winds of Winter* ??

Comment: Good answer. I'd add that a year ago his editor Betsy Wollheim basically said she hadn't heard from him in years (or something like that, I don't quite remember). @Gedgar My guess is that WoW will be published sometimes in the next 10 years, and that DoS will never be published.

Comment: At this point, I’m expecting that reading about Book 3 is far more interesting than reading Book 3 will be.

Comment: There is more updates... I think he's releasing a chapter and has claimed he has restarted writing.

Answer (score 8):

At his reading of Wise Man's fear in Boston last winter, he answered that specific question by saying he really had neglected his wife and baby while he rushed to try and finish book 2 by it's deadline. As a result, he said he will take his time to write book three.

He did not say any certain time frame.

Hope this helps!

Comment: He has other family issues that he's dealing with now, too, which he's prioritizing: http://blog.patrickrothfuss.com/2011/10/faq-why-havent-you-been-posting-on-your-blog/

Answer (score 2):

Actually, he says in an [interview](http://www.sffworld.com/interview/224p0.html) which followed The Name of the Wind that he had both sequels already written and was planning to publish in a regular sequence. In the interview he speaks of "one per year". Given that The Wise Man's Fear was published almost 4 years after the first book though, it's anyone's guess how soon the final installment will hit the shelves (and how much editing he is still planning to do).

Comment: I don't think that's quite accurate:  He wrote 3 books about Kvothe which are "finished" but he's rewriting them for publication.  One thing in particular I remember is that Denna was not in the original.  So it may be closer to the mark to say he's got *very extensive notes*.

Answer (score 1):

I went to a book signing for the Wise Man's Fear, at Borderlands in San Francisco and this question came up.

The authoritative answer for this from Patrick Rothfuss himself was, and I quote, "One huNDRED years!"

He doesn't want to give a close deadline that can be missed, I would guess a couple of years though.

Comment: Can you put the link you got the quote from?

Answer (score -1):

He states that he likes to take a lot of time to edit and that his fans understand that. Given that, I do know that #2 won't be in paperback until next year, so maybe around then? It would not surprise me if he times it out like that.

Answer (score -1):

According to Goodreads, *King Killer Volume Three: The Doors of Stone* will be released on 5/1/13.

Comment: Goodreads also says [5/1/2025](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2495565.The_Doors_of_Stone). I suspect the real pub date will be between those dates.

Comment: @sjl - I will take that bet.

Comment: Goodreads says many things. That doesn't make them true

Comment: @sjl I doubt we'll see it by then...

Comment: How's this answer working out for you?